# Not quantum field theory, but rather ordinary quantum mechanics many-body wave function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction

Reading standard texts of quantum mechanics as such, as distinct from quantum field theory, I am left not knowing the principle that defines a wave function for a closed quantum system constituted by several elementary particles.

I learn that a helium atom can be considered not as a many-particle system, but rather as a single quantum system, constituted though it is by several elementary particles. But I see in the literature mathematical objects that purport to be wave functions for the helium atom, with two 3-fold spatial degrees of freedom, three for each electron. Is there a triple of spatial degrees of freedom that defines the single quantum system that is going to be detected by the single detector permitted by the Born rule? How to apply the Born rule to a system with more than three spatial degrees of freedom.

Comment: What part of the standard construction ("tensor together as many copies of the single-particle Hilbert space(s) as you want") do you find unprincipled or informal?

Comment: Many-particle wave functions are routinely discussed in QM texts, alongside indistinguishability of particles, Pauli principle, Slater determinants, second quantization, etc. (Take, e.g., Landau&Livshits text.) I suggest adding to the text what you already know from the basic QM and formulating clearly where, in your opinion, there is a gap.

Comment: Formally, the concept of a wave function is based on the probability amplitude to detect a particle at a given location. For a multi-particle wave function, it requires the detection of multiple particles at different locations. In that context, the helium atom would be described by a single-particle wave function and not by a multi-particle wave function.

Comment: "What part of the standard construction ("tensor together as many copies of the single-particle Hilbert space(s) as you want") do you find unprincipled or informal?" How does such a mathematical object supply data for the Born rule?

Comment: @Roger Vadim "Many-particle wave functions are routinely ... e.g., Landau&Livshits text. ... your opinion,  there is a gap." Thank you for this helpful pointer to L&L. I will check it and get back.

Comment: @flippiefanus "Formally, ... a multi-particle wave function ... requires the detection of multiple particles ... the helium atom would be described by a single-particle wave function ..." Thank you for your very helpful reply.

Comment: @HTNW "What part of the standard construction ... do you find unprincipled or informal?" How does such a mathematical object supply data for experimental application of the Born rule? Do you mean that simultaneously a detector is needed for each respective particle in the wave function?

Comment: @BayesJeffreysJaynes The Born rule is unchanged. You identify the projection $P$ onto the states which your detector is detecting and compute $|\langle\psi|P|\psi\rangle|^2$ as always.

Comment: @HTNW "The Born rule is unchanged. ... your detector ... as always." Do you mean, in terms of Dirac's account, that, in many experimental runs, you set up many respective different arrangements of slits, choppers, polarizers, etc., leading to the one detector.

Comment: @flippiefanus "detection of multiple particles at different locations". The Born rule refers to many single instances of a quantum system; even if it is constituted by several elementary particles, each instance has to be perfectly coherent with itself. With several detectors, the detections would be incoherent and would not satisfy the principle that the Born rule allows detection of an instance only once without breaking its future perfect self-coherence.